# Sorting list of space separated number strings

Tags: c#, string, sorting

I have a list like this:

```
List<String> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("1 23 4");
strings.Add("1 4 23");
```

When I sort this I want the result to be {(1 4 23), (1 23 4)}. The usual string sort gives {(1 23 4), (1 4 23)} however.

Comment: What is the logic behind it?

Comment: Could you explain the logic in your head that is needed for your _unusual_ sort?

Comment: You can write your own sortmethod with your custom logic.

Comment: Basically I want the list to be sorted based on the numeric value in the corresponding position. Ex:- 23 in position 1 should be compared to 4 and hence come below it in the lexicographic order. What happens right now is 2 being compared to 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = strings.Select(s => new {  
                                    orgstr = s, 
                                    sortstr = String.Join("", s.Split(' ').Select(x => x.PadLeft(10, '0'))) 
                                })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.sortstr)
                    .Select(x => x.orgstr);
```

---

Test case

```
List<String> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("1 23 4 5 6");
strings.Add("1 1 24 2 4");
strings.Add("1 4 23 2 4");
```

Comment: Wow amazing LINQ magic! If you don't mind could you explain how it works?

Comment: @user2277990 I guess if you change last line as `Select(x => x.sortstr)` you will see which string it forms to sort.